# Why does the simple deform modifier not bend when created or strechted on the Y axis?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

When I create a simple cube and stretch (or create other cubes as one object) along the x or Z coordinate it and then add lots of loops cuts it seems to bend just fine. However, if I did all of this along the Y coordinate it messes up really bad. [image]

Above I create a simple cube and stretched it along the X coordinate and add lots of loop cuts. I added the modifier and went to bend and it seems to bend fine.

[image]

Above I did the same thing however I did this along the Y coordinate and as you can see they both have very different results. I also selected X, Y, and Z-axis on the modifier itself still looks bad. I also tried adding an empty but the results still don't improve it. Is there a fix for this? or do I have to create everything on the X-axis? I am relatively new to Blender. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are **two** axes to take into account when using the *Simple Deform* modifier.

1. The axis of **deformation**, set in the modifier, around which, in 'Twist' and 'Bend', vertices rotate.
2. The axis of **extent**, which determines, according to the fraction of the object's bounding box along it, either side of the origin, *how much* the vertices are rotated.

The examples below have their 'Bend' deformation axes set to X, Y and Z:

[image]

as you can see, the axes of extent are Z,Z, and X.

I wish you could set both axes in the modifier. Personally, I always wind up using an Empty as an axis/origin object, and fiddle with it until it works.