# Simple deform only possible with z axis?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, path

I am trying to bend a curve path using a simple deform modifier. But it's only working when I choose the "z-axis." With x and y, the modifier does not have any effect at all. How can I bend it using those axes?

[image: z axis]

[image: y axis]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/221238/35559) will help a bit

Answer (score 0):

The modifier only allows bending when z axis is selected. To make the path bend around another axis, the path itself needs to be rotated.

Comment: Not quite true, if I understand what you mean.. see link in comment to your OP.